# Reduce size of logo on minimum width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

On a [theme based website](http://designlab.co/wrapbootstrap/zerif-html/v1.1/), on its final third stage of collapse, it reduces the width of the logo.

However, they have removed all whitespace from their css making it extremely hard to read.

The problem for me is, the logo is just a bit too big (in width) when it collapses on the minimum width and the logo and the navbar don't sit together.

How would I fix this?

[Reduce width on this page to see what I mean](http://www.selectukdeals.com/template.html)

**Update:** Using @joshhunt code, it now squashes the navbar and logo together

CSS (vanilla bootstrap except for):

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        max-width: 200px;
        height: auto; /* So the image doesn't distort */
    }
}
```

HTML page:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.htm"><img src="logo.png" alt="SelectUKDeals"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
      <input class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update #2**: So it went from going like this-

[image: before]

to this

[image: after]

**Solution:** I didn't add the `class="logo"` to the image :( It works perfectly now

Comment: I don't get what is the point. Could you please clarify.

Comment: Additionally showing us some code would be nice.

Comment: If you click on the website, you'll see when you resize it down, on the very last reduction, the logo reduces in size that one bit. Ok I shall give you a url to what I mean.

Comment: Wait you them to be a different lines? I thought you wanted the to make the logo image smaller??

Comment: I did want the logo smaller, but it changed from previously being on another line. I shall re-edit to clarify a bit better

Comment: I've updated my answer. Also for next time please post any relevant css as well.

Comment: its vanilla bootstrap, it would have just been chunks of useless code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to change the max-width on the logo, for example:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .logo {
        max-width: 200px;
        height: auto; /* So the image doesn't distort */
    }
}
```

This would set a max-width of 200px on the "logo" class when the screen width is less or equal to 480px.

I use max-width just in case you change the image and it ends up being smaller or you the image container ends up being smaller and you want it to fit to that (using width: 100%;) but you could just use width and it would probably work just as well.

**Update**

To make navbar-brand go on a new line you just need to add `clear: both` ([more info on clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)) to it inside the media query. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        clear: both;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, well I used the equivalent using my code I think, but it isn't working for me

Comment: @omega_prime Edit your question and add the relevant code please. Also making a jsfiddle would be nice but it's not compulsory.

Comment: Done sir as requested

Comment: Hmm, it seems I am not being clear at all. A new line is not what I wanted and it is pointless me giving you vanilla bootstrap css code. I haven't changed a single thing in it yet other than your code of course

Comment: @omega_prime If you haven't used any custom css don't worry about it. What are the dimensions of your image? (Or even better add it to your question). And what do you want it to do?

Comment: It is currently width 250 x 50, when it gets to the minimum width, i want to try and reduce this to 200 with the relevant height so it doesn't distort.

Comment: @omega_prime Sorry I don't understand, what's wrong with my original answer? If possible please post images of how it currently looks and how you want it to look. Also you can use this resource: http://www.bootply.com/wzuvJ0aa9I

Comment: It squashes them together. I shall post a screenshot. The mobile device on your code, new lines it on that link :S

Comment: Screenshot attached, it will show you exactly what I mean then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56492/discussion-between-joshhunt-and-omega-prime).